# SSIS Package Based on a avariable

Tags: ssis

Hi I've an SSIS Package which Does tasks like a)Truncate Last 7 days data from a table if any and then re-load it and all theses are placed in a sequence container and it run's fine.Now I'm planning to remove the hard coded value of 7 and introduce a variable NoOfDays which I can provide at run time.Can this be achieved?

I added a variable and tried to map it to the parameter of the ExecuteSQL Task...It gave the following error:

I even want the value to be available to the next step Data Flow Task

```
[Execute SQL Task] Error: Executing the query "delete  from USER_CONTENT where CONVERT..." failed with the following error: "The variable name '@NoOfDays' has already been declared. Variable names must be unique within a query batch or stored procedure.
Statement(s) could not be prepared.". Possible failure reasons: Problems with the query, "ResultSet" property not set correctly, parameters not set correctly, or connection not established correctly.
```

The query I'm using is

```
delete from USER_CONTENT 
where CONVERT(date,ISSUE_DATE)>=CONVERT(DATE,GETDATE()-7)
```

and it is against an OLE-DB connection.

Comment: Can you post the SQL that you have in the container, indicate the type of connection (OLE DB/ADO.Net etc.), also indicate how you mapped the variable in the property page. Consider posting _all_ relevant information in future. There are many online guides to setting up parameter mapping, perhaps you could refer to one.

Comment: Hi the SQL That I'm using is delete from USER_CONTENT where CONVERT(date,ISSUE_DATE)>=CONVERT(DATE,GETDATE()-7) and It's a OLEDB Connection.

Comment: I've added your query to the question. Now that we can see your query it's obvious that you do't have a parameter placeholder (as stated in DroidSlaves answer). Take a look at this: http://sqlage.blogspot.com.au/2013/07/ssis-how-to-pass-parameter-value-to-ole.html
and post back with any specific questions.

Answer (score 0):

I do not have enough points to post a comment so I will have to ask you this way: are you using query parameters with a "?", if not, then in order to use a package variable with a stored procedure, you will need to write your statement to use them, also, don't name your parameters, use the default 0,1,2 etc.. that the package assigns.

Comment: Hi Droid,I've not used a pamaeter with '?' and I don't use an SP either...I just wanna pass a different number at runtime instead of 7 in the above Execute SQL Task...

Comment: Are you using a variable to store the value you want to place in your parameter? Ideally this would be the best (only?) approach to passing a value to a parameter, it's the only way I have done it other than to hard code it.

Comment: Also, GETDATE()-7 seems unreliable to me as it doesn't indicate precisely what you are subtracting. I would use the DATEADD function instead and add negative 7 days to GETDATE().